# Bash Array From ec2 describe-images

Tags: arrays, bash, amazon-ec2

How can I get an array like `ARR[ImageID]=CreationDate` from the tab-delimited output from my describe-images variable?

```
IMAGES=$(aws ec2 describe-images --output text --query 'Images[].[ImageId,CreationDate]');
```

Output is similar to:

```
ami-11xxxxx    2015-03-06:12:00:00
ami-12xxxxx    2015-03-06:12:00:00
ami-13xxxxx    2015-03-06:12:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this?

```
IMAGES=$(aws ec2 describe-images --output text --query 'Images[].[ImageId,CreationDate]' |awk '{print $1 "=" $2}');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash 

#your data
IMAGES="
ami-11xxxxx    2015-03-06:12:00:11
ami-12xxxxx    2015-03-06:12:00:12
ami-13xxxxx    2015-03-06:12:00:13  
"

#declare associative memory
typeset -A ARR

index=""
for s in ${IMAGES}
do
   if [ -z ${index} ]; then
     index=$s
   else
     ARR[${index}]=$s
     index=""
   fi
done 

#test
echo ${ARR[ami-11xxxxx]}
echo ${ARR[ami-12xxxxx]}
```

result :

```
 2015-03-06:12:00:11
 2015-03-06:12:00:12
```